# Export data as C# / VB format to use them in EF Code First's Database Initialization

Tags: database, entity-framework, export, code-first

Some times, sample data is important but boring to generate due to many related tables.
So, in Entity Framework Code First, I think it's an elegant way to insert them in DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges::Seed().

But is there a way to export existing data from database back to a string as C# / VB sentences that insert poco objects?

If it works, we may use it to backup data gracefully, or save to multiple .cs by scenes, switch them as needed to better our test, etc.

### DATABASE EXPORTS AS THE FOLLOWING CODE:

```
var students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student { FirstMidName = "Carson",   LastName = "Alexander", },
    new Student { FirstMidName = "Meredith", LastName = "Alonso",    },
    new Student { FirstMidName = "Arturo",   LastName = "Anand",     },
    // ...
};
students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I have always done this by serialising the seed data to XML or JSON and importing it from a file on seed

Comment: Is there some tools suggested? I want to reduce the steps it needs.

Comment: Ive always done it myself, serialisation is pretty easy

Comment: Do you really need to drop and create database in every change? Why don't you just use data migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Luke suggested in his comment. the best way is to generate Json files for your seed data.

[in this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/producing-json-documents-from-sql-server-queries-via-tsql/), you can find the easy way to **generate your Json from SQL query.**

**Then all you need is to read them by Newtonsoft.Json**

e.g.

```
var countriesStream = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("jsonFile.json"));
try
{
    countriesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Country>>(countriesStream.ReadToEnd());
}
```